# ov7670 + Sd Card + arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I have three devices for making a motion activated security camera system:

- this is the camera : [LINK](http://urun.gittigidiyor.com/ev-elektronigi/arduino-pic-kamera-modulu-ov7660-134509055)  OV 7670
- this is the SD Card module: [LINK](http://urun.gittigidiyor.com/ev-elektronigi/arduino-sd-kart-modulu-140174113?opi=132220334)
- and a basic motion Sensor: PIR with 3 pin

I have an Arduino UNO and an Arduino Mega 2560.

I can connect the SD card and sensor, they work fine but I cannot connect the camera as there are not enough pins for it on UNO.

Is there a chance to connect all of them without any additional device?

I saw some working project with additional device (arducam) but I do not have much money to spend on this project.

Comment: Do this camera module have AL422 FIFO?

Comment: I think both the Camera module and the SD (can't see underside) require 3.3v logic, while the Uno and Mega have 5v I/O. So you probably need some logic level shifting. Other than that, I see no problem.

Comment: to Gerben: Yes camera need 3.3v logic, but SD card module also have 5v. @AndrewPaes I don't think so. It was cheapest module when I buy ($10). OV 7670+AL422 FIFO was $22. What is AL422 ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem as you mister LuffyTheKaizoku. I bought the non-FIFO and then bought the FIFO version of the OV7670 but still not found a way to program it. I am also trying to save the code to an SD card! Did you manage to find a solution for this problem?
If you did, I would really really need your help. Thank you very much in advanced!
Felipe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This camera module requires the use of additional hardware, as the camera and Arduino operating frequencies differ, which can result in loss of synchronization and changes to the image, and other connection problems.

Thus, we must use an integrated circuit intermediary, making the connection between the camera and the Arduino. The function of this chip is to receive the camera information, store them and then send them to the Arduino using the digital doors, much faster than if we used the serial communication.

An example of an integrated circuit that could be used is AL422, suitable for treating a video signal, which also is embedded in **some** OV7670 modules.

Looking like the connection pins behave in 7670, your module should be equal to it. So spare pins to be able to make other necessary connections.

[image: 7670 with AL422 pin]

Would better check the connection through the datasheets:

[7670 datasheet](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/document-viewer/?pdf_file=OV7670-CMOS-VGA-Camera-Datasheet.pdf)

[AL422 datasheet](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/document-viewer/?pdf_file=AL422-FIFO-Datasheet.pdf)

[An example of project](http://nicolasfley.fast-page.org/?page_id=35)

But to answer your question; You'll need to purchase a piece more if you don't have AL442.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. I found the same project yesterday and I realised that I need Al422. After all these research , I also learned there isn't any shop to buy AL422 in my country (internet shop). So I give up and order new camera module. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You don't need these 10Ohms (by the way totally insufficient if needed), because RPi and the camera JTRON function at 3.3V.

Comment: Example link goes to an adware download site now :(